# How does adding an irrelevant feature affect the accuracy of a model?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-mining, feature-selection

My main question is how could irrelevant features decrease the accuracy?

Example:

Lets say we have a feature and the data can be perfectly classified with 100% accuracy using SVM. How can the addition of a new irrelevant feature decrease the accuracy?

Please answer this without example first and then use the example for easy understanding in a 2D plane.

Comment: Adding an irrelevant feature can only cause overfitting, which will generally lead to decreased accuracy.  Which part of this is causing confusion?

Comment: This is algorithm-dependent, many will not have decreased accuracy.

Comment: This seems like a bold statement.  Which algorithms don't overfit?

Comment: @dsaxton That isn't the point. Pick 1D linearly separable data, just as OP said. Add a random variable. Train a forest or a maximal margin classifier on both variables. Why do you think always accuracy would change (i.e. be less than 100%)?

Comment: @Firebug Due to overfitting.  It's easy to imagine how this can happen.  Say the true boundary is a vertical line through the origin $x_1 = 0$ and now you add another dimension $x_2$.  The decision boundary is not going to be a perfect vertical line even though it should be, so for fixed $x_1$ you will make different decisions based on $x_2$ and will be making mistakes when you weren't before.

Comment: @dsaxton I can see what you mean, if the classes are separable but really close together, but this is now sounds data-dependent as well.

Comment: @Firebug thank you I think you cleared my doubt very well geometrically

Comment: @Firebug Why the decision boundary should move? In the first case, the boundary is a point $x^*$ that separates the two classes. In the second case, it is a vertical line that passes through $x^*$. The only way I can imagine that this can change is how these new points affect the **estimation** of the decision boundary.

Answer (score 8):

1. With a [consistent estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator), your estimate of the irrelevant feature's effect will go to zero as number of observations goes to infinity. In the limit, nothing will happen.
2. But with finite data, you're giving your algorithm the opportunity to find [spurious relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship), to spuriously find that the irrelevant feature does predict your outcome variable.

Including an irrelevant feature gives your estimator new ways to go wrong without any expected benefit. It's like placing a button in a car that should never be pressed; nothing good can be expected to come from it!